# .Net Core Identity. How to get instance of UserManager

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, identity

I am running into the following error while trying to get an instance of UserManager:

```
System.MissingMethodException
 HResult=0x80131513
 Message=Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.DataProtectorTokenProvider`1..ctor(Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.IDataProtectionProvider, Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>)'.
```

Here's my code:

```
 var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider
           .GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();
```

This used to work just fine until I made to the following changes as part of implementing EmailConfirmation.

```
  services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(opt =>
            {
                opt.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
                opt.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
                opt.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                opt.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                opt.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = "emailconfirmation";
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MeerkatContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddTokenProvider<EmailConfirmationTokenProvider<AppUser>>("emailconfirmation");
        services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(opt =>
            opt.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2));
        services.Configure<EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions>(opt =>
            opt.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(3));
```

Here's the EmailConfirmationProvider

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

public class EmailConfirmationTokenProvider<TUser> : DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser> where TUser : class
{
    public EmailConfirmationTokenProvider(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider,
        IOptions<EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions> options)
        : base(dataProtectionProvider, options)
    {
    }
}
```

I am on .Net Core 7.

Thanks for any insight in what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why aren't you using dependency injection?

Comment: Hi @JonathanWood, thanks for the reply.  This code is part of my database seeding code that is done in the Startup method. It is done here:    void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)

Comment: Where is your  ILogger<DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser>> logger ? I create the EmailConfirmationTokenProvider<TUser>, it needs ILogger<DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser>> logger. Besides, what's your EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions class looks like ?

Comment: "var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider
           .GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();" Where do you put this code ?